# What does `strcpy(x+1, SEQX)` do?

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm wondering what this syntax of `strcpy()` does in line 65 and 66:

```
 24 #define SEQX "TTCATA"
 25 #define SEQY "TGCTCGTA"
 61   M = strlen(SEQX);
 62   N = strlen(SEQY);
 63   x = malloc(sizeof(char) * (M+2)); /* +2: leading blank, and trailing \0 */
 64   y = malloc(sizeof(char) * (N+2));
 65   strcpy(x+1, SEQX);            /* x_1..x_M now defined; x_0 undefined */
 66   strcpy(y+1, SEQY);            /* y_1..y_N now defined; y_0 undefined */
```

I know it's copying `SEQX` and `SEQY` into `x` and `y` but I don't understand what does the `+1` do? What's the formal name of this type of operation?

Comment: The name might be "pointer arithmetic". `x+1` means the address of the array element after the one that `x` is the address of.

Comment: @MattMcNabb so `x` is a pointer here?

Comment: If that's all the code provided, then `x[0]` and `y[0]` are junk. It almost looks/sounds like its missing an assignment into `x[0]`, like `x[0] = ' '` (initialize as a space).

Comment: `&x[1]` could also have been used, i.e. the address of the second array element.

Comment: @olala yes, the `malloc` function returns a pointer to the first element of a block of memory that it allocates

Comment: @Ja͢ck hmm, how to use `&x[1]` ?

Comment: `strcpy(&x[1], SEQX);` - depends a bit on what you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pointer + offset` notation is used as a convenient means to reference memory locations.

In your case, the `pointer` is provided by `malloc()` after allocating sufficient heap memory, and represents an array of `M + 2` elements of type `char`, thus the notation as used in your code represents the following address:

```
<x + 1 * sizeof(char)>
```

And this also happens to be the same as:

```
&x[1]
```

In other words, the address of `x[1]` (second element of `x`). After the `strcpy()` operation the memory would look like this:

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7]
??? 'T' 'T' 'C' 'A' 'T' 'A' '\0'
^
x
```

In other words:

```
strcmp(x + 1, SEQX) == 0
```

Note that before practical use of `x` as a string, the first memory location should be defined, i.e.

```
x[0] = '='; // now the string holds "=TTCATA"
```

Answer (score 7):

`strcpy(x+1, SEQX);` copies the SEQX into x buffer but it leaves the first byte unchanged. At the comment it says: `/* +2: leading blank, and trailing \0 */`. it is skipped deliberately.

This is the structure of the allocated buffer:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| x |x+1|x+2|x+3|...|   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. is `x` now a pointer to a copy of `SEQX` and it's first element points to the second element of the `SEQX`?

Comment: No, `x`'s second element is a copy of the first element of `SEQX`, and so on. From the code you show above we know nothing about the first elements of `x` and `y`.